# I am trying to have this link open in a new tab so users dont have to leave my site but it is not working with _blank

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, nonblank

The link opens but not in a new tab.I am trying to have this link open in a new tab so users don't have to leave my site. I am using `target="_blank"` but it is not working

```
<BottomNavigation className={classes.root}>
    <BottomNavigationAction
      label="Instagram"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      href="https://www.instagram.com/_vhub/"
      target="_blank"
      icon={
        <img
          src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dvqyek3sb/image/upload/v1566370518/instagram_hmfqj5.png"
          alt="Instagrm"
        />
      }
    />
```

Comment: You need to show the code that is inside `<BottomNavigationAction />` otherwise there is no way of telling why the <a> is not getting the target prop.

Comment: There is not <a> tag sir this is all of the code im passing the link to BottomNavigationAction

Comment: What you see is the code inside of bottomNavigation Action thanks for the downvote though

Comment: I tried with the a tag got the same result

Comment: What is the generated html?

Comment: So first of all I have no idea what 'BottomNavigationAction' is hence the downvote, you needed to explicitly explain that you were using a Material UI component here to save me googling. I also have no idea if you are talking about React or React-Native? Finally I looked at the docs for `BottomNavigationAction` and there is no prop for href OR target so how can it possibly work?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try put your whole component inside anchor tags or Link component and set their properties:

rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/_vhub/" target="_blank"

Comment: I treid this and still got the same result

Comment: Have you removed those properties from your BottomNavigationAction properties?

Comment: You could also make method: 
handleInstagramClick = () => {
  window.open(https://www.instagram.com/_vhub/, '_blank');
}

And then add click handler on your component:
  <BottomNavigationAction onClick={this.handlePoliciesClick} />

Comment: Bleh your handles are for class components hook me please haha